# Proper way to init native library state in Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Unfortunately, I have to use a C library with internal state in my Android project. The library includes state-maintaining functions `init()` and `release()`. I have written a wrapper class with static `init()` and `release()` members. Then I added calls to these methods in main activity's `OnCreate()` and `OnDestroy()` respectively.

And that is where I got a problem. When the system is low on memory and some other activity is in foreground, main activity gets killed and `release()` is called. Therefore, all subsequent calls to native library fail spectacularly.

The question is, how to ensure main activity is never killed? Or perhaps there is a better way to call the native functions than doing it in the activity's callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. You can override it and declare your custom `Application` class in your `Manifest`. Do the initialisation on the `onCreate()` of your `Application` class.

I am not sure what your library acutally does, maybe you can elaborate, and depending on your needs you can also consider running a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which will be less likely to be killed by `Android` than your `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks, subclassing `Application` seems a fine idea to me. As for the library, it's nothing special, just some number-crunching routines. On `init()` it allocates and precalculates its internal tables and stuff like that.